# Java While-Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

For some reason I cannot get it so when I put in a incorrect answer it only prints one 'wrong' message instead of three. I checked other threads but found none. I would appreciate a solution thanks.

```
public class GuessLetter {
public static void main(String args[])
throws java.io.IOException {
    char ch, answer = 'k';
    int loop = -1;

    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
    System.out.println("Can you guess it: ");

    while (loop < 0) {
        ch = (char) System.in.read();

        if (ch == answer) {
            loop++;
            System.out.println("**CORRECT**");
        } else
            System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask (as it's written the code only prints "wrong" once, and it doesn't really imply that it's supposed to print thrice), could you please clarify?

Comment: After pressing the key, are you pressing another key like `<Enter>` for example?

Comment: You get wrong three times because you read <answer> CR LF. That are the three char you get by System.in.read() add System.in.readLine() after reading the character

Comment: I would look into Scanner

Comment: The `if`'s _then_ clause has braces but the `else` clause doesn't. My eyes are in pain...